# Phil Strugeon REST server - is there really security vulnerability in Digest Auth or I misunderstood something?

Tags: codeigniter, rest

Recently I downloaded [Phil Strugeon REST server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) for CodeIgniter.
I reviewed source code and when I come to Digest authentication I saw following code:

```
if ($this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'))
{
    $digest_string = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_DIGEST');
}
elseif ($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'))
{
    $digest_string = $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
}
else
{
    $digest_string = "";
}
```

And bit later after some checks for absence of $digest_string and presence of username:

```
// This is the valid response expected
$A1 = md5($digest['username'].':'.$this->config->item('rest_realm').':'.$valid_pass);
$A2 = md5(strtoupper($this->request->method).':'.$digest['uri']);
$valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$digest['nonce'].':'.$digest['nc'].':'.$digest['cnonce'].':'.$digest['qop'].':'.$A2);

if ($digest['response'] != $valid_response)
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
}
```

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) I see following text about HTTP Digest Auth:

> For subsequent requests, the hexadecimal request counter (nc) must be greater than the last value it used – otherwise an attacker could simply "replay" an old request with the same credentials. It is up to the server to ensure that the counter increases for each of the nonce values that it has issued, rejecting any bad requests appropriately.
>
> The server should remember nonce values that it has recently generated. It may also remember when each nonce value was issued, expiring them after a certain amount of time. If an expired value is used, the server should respond with the "401" status code and add stale=TRUE to the authentication header, indicating that the client should re-send with the new nonce provided, without prompting the user for another username and password.

However I can't see anything about checking cnonce, nc or nonce in source code.
Does it mean that somebody who recorded request from Client to Server that passed authentification may just "replay" it in future and receive fresh value of resource?

Is it really vulnarability? Or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too when looking at codeigniter-restserver.   It IS vulnerable to replay attacks because, as you said, it does not enforce the nonce.

Digest authentication requires a handshake:

1. client makes request with Authorization. It will fail because the client does not yet know the nonce
2. server responds with WWW-Authenticate header, that contains the correct nonce to use
3. client makes same request using the nonce provided in the server response
4. server checks that the nonces match and provides the requested url.

To accomplish this, you'll need to start a session on your REST server to remember the nonce.  An easy scheme for ensuring nonce is always unique is to base it on current time using a function such as uniqid()